# Error in my script SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this script and he return this error in console **SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** but i dont found where is the error in my code.

```
<video autopĺay id="cam" width="400" height="400" muted></video>

<script>  

    const cam = document.getElementById('cam')

    const startVideo = () => {

        var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function(mediaStream) {
                var video = document.querySelector('video');
                video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                    video.play();
                };
            })
        .catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.
}

Promise.all([
       faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",
       faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_landmark_68_model-weights_manifest.json') %>", //desenha os traços do rosto
       faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_recognition_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",//faz o conhecimento do rosto
       faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_expression_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",//detecta expressoes
       faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/age_gender_model-weights_manifest.json') %>", //idade e genero
       faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-weights_manifest.json') %>" // usada para detectar rosto
]).then(startVideo)

cam.addEventListener('play', async() => {
    const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(cam)
})  



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of all your `faceapi.nets.` lines inside the big `Promise.all`, you end all the lines with just a comma rather than ending with `),`. Since you are calling `loadFromUri`, you need to close the function before moving onto the next one.

Comment: @TWS Make sure to mark the correct answer by clicking the tick on the side of the question so if anyone else is having the same issue as you, they know where to look :)

Comment: Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models',
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models',
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models',
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models',
  )]).then(startVideo) even though i get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all([
       faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",
       faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_landmark_68_model-weights_manifest.json') %>", //desenha os traços do rosto
       faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_recognition_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",//faz o conhecimento do rosto
       faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/face_expression_model-weights_manifest.json') %>",//detecta expressoes
       faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/age_gender_model-weights_manifest.json') %>", //idade e genero
       faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri("<%= asset_path('face-api.js/models/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-weights_manifest.json') %>" // usada para detectar rosto
]).then(startVideo)
```

faceapi.nets need additional ) later %>"